# Ant JavaFX Include If

Tags: java, ant, javafx

I'm using ant to package a JavaFX-based application. No problem with doing the actual JavaFX stuff, except that `fx:jar` doesn't support the `if` or `condition` tags. I want to dynamically include some platform-specific libraries, depending on a variable i set. Currently I have this:

```
<fx:fileset dir="/my/classes/folder">
    <include name="**/*lib1.dylib" if="??"/>
    <include name="**/*lib2.dll" if="??" />
    <include name="**/*lib3.dll" if="??" />
</fx:fileset>
```

I want to run this target multiple times, with a different variable value depending on the platform. It seems you can not do something like:

```
    <include name="**/*lib3.dll" if="platform=mac" />
```

So I'm stuck. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link for you: [How to make a conditional decision in an Ant build script based on operating system](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/how-conditional-operation-ant-script-operating-system)

And a piece of the ant script included in the page:

```
<condition property="isMac">
    <os family="mac" />
</condition>

<condition property="isWindows">
    <os family="windows" />
</condition>

<condition property="isUnix">
    <os family="unix" />
</condition>

...

<fx:fileset dir="/my/classes/folder">
    <include name="**/*lib1.dylib" if="isMac"/>
    <include name="**/*lib2.dll" if="isWindows" />
    <include name="**/*lib3.dll" if="isUnix" />
</fx:fileset>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you copied the files you want conditionally included in another, build-temporary directory and then include a `<fx:fileset>` in the `<fx:jar>` for this directory.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following:

```
<target name="all" depends="getDependencies">

        <!-- Built x86 jars -->
        <antcall target="-buildModes">
          <param name="platform" value = "Win86"/>
          <param name="platform.x86" value="true"/>
        </antcall>

        <!-- Built x64 jars -->
        <antcall target="-buildModes">
              <param name="platform" value = "Win64"/>
          <param name="platform.x64" value="true"/>
        </antcall>

        <!-- Built mac jars -->
        <antcall target="-buildModes">
              <param name="platform" value = "Mac"/>
          <param name="platform.mac" value="true"/>
        </antcall>
    </target>
```

It passes the platform parameter so that the target has a new version each time. A global parameter would have been immutable.